# How to get the full StackTrace when using SuperDevMode in GWT 2.7?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, stack-trace

I use GWT 2.7 with super dev mode. When it comes to an exception the stack trace looks like the following:

```
SEVERE: UncaughtExceptioncom.github.nmorel.gwtjackson.client.exception.JsonDeserializationException: Unknown property 'uploadImageId'
    at Unknown.AHc_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.vHc_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.OHc_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.VHc_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.aIc_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.gIc_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.rDc_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.qDc_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.vNb_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.nNb_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.oNb_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.pNb_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.gNb_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.fNb_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.$Cc_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.ZCc_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.zOm_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.ZDe_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.aEe_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
```

I have a GWT project running in a GWT-PhoneGap environment on my iPhone and I use the Safari Console for Debugging.

**How can I get the full stack track deobfuscated with SuperDevMode?**

Edit: I also use the following flag:

```
-XmethodNameDisplayMode Full
```

It does not work.

Comment: From the docs it looks like you might be able to use the command line option ```-XmethodNameDisplayMode       EXPERIMENTAL: Specifies method display name mode for chrome devtools: NONE, ONLY_METHOD_NAME, ABBREVIATED or FULL (defaults to NONE)```

Comment: @Alex I have a GWT project running in a GWT-PhoneGap environment on my iPhone and I use the Safari Console for Debugging. It still does not work with this flag.

Comment: The [doc](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html) says that this option is for "chrome devtools."  Is it supposed to work with Safari?  Have you tried with Chrome?

Comment: It says (Unknown Source). Have you included the source code in your GWT project?

Answer (score 0):

As of GWT 2.7.0, this isn't possible. You might want to follow [this GWT bug](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/7457).

The `-XmethodNameDisplayMode Full` only applies to the browser's dev tools. So if you set this parameter and set a breakpoint in the source code, the method names of the call stack will be displayed correctly in dev tools. This doesn't affect the call stack produced by log output (which is what you posted in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the compiler option `style` to `PRETTY` or `DETAILED`

```
-style                         Script output style: DETAILED, OBFUSCATED or PRETTY (defaults to OBFUSCATED)
```

see [GWT compiler options](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#What_options_can_be_passed_to_development_mode)